# How to update entire column with values in list using Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a dataset stored locally in an sqlite3 database.  I extracted a column, performed some operations and now want to replace ALL of the values in the database column.  How can I do this?

The length of the column and the list are guaranteed to be the same length.  I simply want to update the table with the new values.  Is there an easy way to do this all at once?

Using python 2.7

Edited to add:

myList is a pandas series backed by a numpy array of dtype 'object'.  The table column, myCol is text formatted.

```
In [1]: curr.execute('UPDATE test SET myCol= ?', myList)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
f:\python\<ipython-input-52-ea41c426502a> in <module>()
----> 1 curr.execute('UPDATE test SET myCol = ?', myList)

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 401125 supplied.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`.executemany()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) instead:

```
curr.executemany('UPDATE test SET myCol= ?', myList)
```

However, `myList` *must* be a sequence of tuples here. If it is not, a generator expression will do to create these tuples:

```
curr.executemany('UPDATE test SET myCol= ?', ((val,) for val in myList))
```

Demonstration (with insertions):

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE test (myCol)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10542f1f0>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> myList = ('foo', 'bar', 'spam')
>>> conn.executemany('INSERT into test values (?)', ((val,) for val in myList))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10542f180>
>>> list(conn.execute('select * from test'))
[(u'foo',), (u'bar',), (u'spam',)]
```

Note that for an `UPDATE` statement, you *have* to have a `WHERE` statement to identify *what row* to update. An `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` filter will update *all* rows.

Make sure your data has a row identifier to go with it; in this case it may be easier to use named parameters instead:

```
my_data = ({id=1, value='foo'}, {id=2, value='bar'})
cursor.executemany('UPDATE test SET myCol=:value WHERE rowId=:id', my_data)
```

Comment: This seems to be updating ALL the values of myCol with each value found in myList.  The end result is that every row of the updated column has the last value found in myList.  What I want is: `row1 = myList[0], row2=myList[1]`, etc...

Comment: @Zelazny7: No, `executemany()` iterates over `myList` and effectively calls `execute()` for each entry. This requires each `myList` entry to be a tuple though.

Comment: @Zelazny7: Ah, I see the problem. You have *no* `WHERE` clause. How do you expect the database to know what `myCol` belongs with what row?

Comment: That's just it, though. I want to do a straight replace of the entire column.  I don't know much (anything) about how the rows are stored. Perhaps I naively assumed they were in the same order as when they were stored?  I am only using this db as out-of-core storage for a table of data.  The number of rows will ALWAYS be the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!  I think I can add an integer index column and just enumerate(mylist) in the executemany().

Comment: @Zelazny7: Even if your SQLite schema doesn't include an explicit identifier, there is an internal row id that you can select on too. See http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html. You need to explicitly *query* for it when you fetch the data, and you need to use the same id when using `UPDATE` to match the rows again.