# Python sqlite3 'executemany' not successfully updating my database

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, executemany

I'm trying to extract a column from my database, apply a transformation, and create a new column with the results.

I ultimately want to save the local variable 'new_proba' (which has a length of 740, the same length as my database) as a new column called 'predict_proba_tplus1'. From reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688462/how-to-update-entire-column-with-values-in-list-using-sqlite3), I've learned that the UPDATE function expects a tuple.

I created an 'IDs' list which matches the indexID column in the database and then zipped it with 'new_proba' to create the tuple which outputs '(0.56298709097028454, 0), (0.54392926856501334, 1),' etc.

The function below doesn't actually throw any error, but it only creates the column 'predict_proba_tplus1' and doesn't fill in any values which I'd expect c.executemany() to do - I'm left with a new column filled with NULL values. It makes me think there's something wrong with the WHERE statement - i.e. it's not matching the indexID column to the IDs variable for some reason, despite the numbers being the same.

Any insight would be hugely appreciated.

```
def update_class_proba(path):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    cursor = c.execute('SELECT text, indexID FROM reuters_test_X')
    all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
    X = vect.transform(x[0] for x in all_rows)
    new_proba = list(clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1])
    IDs = list(np.arange(0, 740, 1))
    new_proba_tuple = list(zip(new_proba,IDs))
    c.execute('ALTER TABLE reuters_test_X ADD COLUMN predict_proba_tplus1 REAL')
    c.executemany('UPDATE reuters_test_X SET predict_proba_tplus1=? WHERE indexID=?', new_proba_tuple)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `new_proba_tuple` contains the right data in the right format?  You give some sample contents in the third paragraph in your post, but the format seems odd -- it's enclosed in quotes (implying it's actually a string), and it's __not__ enclosed in square brackets (implying it's not a list).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the output format (I added the quote in the last post:
[(0.56298709097028454, 0), (0.54392926856501334, 1), (0.58659573866520598, 2), etc

Comment: Try a single `execute` statement with one row of data and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. I just created a new variable 
    new_data = [(0.56,7), (0.56,8), (0.56,9)]
which both execute and executemany statements work for. So the problem looks to be my list of tuples. I can't understand why though, as it seems to be in exactly the same format as the toy one I've just created.

Comment: Maybe the values in `new_proba_tuple` _print_ like floating-point numbers but are really something else?  Try printing the `type()`.

Comment: Like this?:
    >>> type(new_proba_tuple)
    <class 'list'>
    >>> type(new_data)
    <class 'list'>

Comment: We want the type of the items _in_ new_proba_tuple, not new_proba_tuple itself.  Try this: `type(new_proba_tuple[0][0])`

Comment: Ahh, thanks. This gives the following: >>> type(new_proba_tuple[0][0]) <class 'numpy.float64'> >>> type(new_proba_tuple[0][1]) <class 'numpy.int64'> >>> type(new_data[0][0]) <class 'float'> >>> type(new_data[0][1]) <class 'int'> Do you think it doesn't like that the 'IDs' part of the tuple is a numpy int64?

Comment: I would try converting those items to plain `int` and `float` values.  The database might not be able to handle the `numpy` types.

Comment: Try this: `new_proba = list(float(z) for z in clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1])` and `IDs = list(int(zz) for zz in np.arange(0, 740, 1))`

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for the help. I would 'accept' this but I'm not sure how to (or if I'm even able to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values aren't plain `float`; they're `numpy.float64`, which the database can't handle.

Convert your values to plain `float` and `int` like this:

```
new_proba = list(float(z) for z in clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1])
IDs = list(int(zz) for zz in np.arange(0, 740, 1))
```